# How do I create a group made out of different columns?

Tags: r, grouping

I'm new to R so sorry if this is a stupid question: I have a data set made out of data from a questionnaire.
I want to group different answers together by concept - which means that I have several columns of data from each person for the same topic; for example 5 different answers about topic X, 5 for topic Y and so on. I would like to create groups for all answers to topic X, Y etc. Is that possible? So far I've only seen people creating groups by columns.

Comment: It would be much easier to explain what you are trying to achieve if you provide an example of your data, and an example of the what the output would look like from that example data.

Comment: Okay, so let's suppose I asked people to rate 6 items from 0-6. These items belong to two concepts X and Y. both have 3 items. I want to create a group for all answer of all people to item x1, x2 and x3 and the same for y1, y2 and y3. Is that possible? - I would love to show you the output but I don't quite know how to poste the table

Comment: If you are trying to combine the categories into meaningful factors, exploratory factor analysis (EFA) may be an option.

Comment: Wait what is your goal with this data? I guess I should have asked that first.

Comment: thanks @ShawnHemelstrand, but that's not what I'm trying to do - I have asked people about three different topics using multiple items and just want all the items of one topic in a group

Comment: @CharlotteSophie Yes it's possible, but it's easier to provide code for these steps if there is a dataset to work from. Otherwise, roughly I'd point to the `dplyr::case_when()` function that is useful for multiple if-else combinations. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Comment: Dear @Phil , thanks, is there an easy way to paste the dataset?

Comment: You can copy and paste the output of `dput(head(mydf))` where `mydf` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: unfortunately, it says the comment is too long...